# Is there a versioning system for digitalink models

Tags: android, google-mlkit

- If so, does update take place automatically

  - What happens to the old models?
  - Is there a way to lock a specific model version

Answer (score 0):

For digital ink, the model version is determined by the SDK version. For example, if you keep using com.google.mlkit:digital-ink-recognition:18.0.0, you will always download the same models.

When you upgrade to a new version of the SDK, you may get a newer version of model.